# How to create JDBC data source in Oracle WebLogic server properly?

Tags: java, macos, networking, weblogic

I'm trying to create a JDBC data source in Oracle WebLogic server and getting some error. I can log in the web console http://localhost:7001/console using user name + password and I followed the [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5W2tm89yN4A)  /   [tutorial page](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/fmw/wls/12c/12_1_3/04/04-ConfigDataSource/configds.html) -  *Configuring a JDBC data source* as same.

I have a wireless connection and I get the Host name (# 12 in the tutorial ) by typing

```
ipconfig getifaddr en0
```

in the Mac OS terminal. It returns 10.131.173.138 ( the same format, I changed three random digits ) and I put it inside the **Host name** and also filled up all other information's. However, after that when I'm trying to test the set up by clicking *Test Configuration*, it returns me the following errors that I provided below -

***Connection test failed.
Message icon - Error IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:800)
oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:793)
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:33)
oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:614)
weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.DataSourceUtil.testConnection0(DataSourceUtil.java:340)
weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.DataSourceUtil.access$000(DataSourceUtil.java:22)
weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.DataSourceUtil$1.run(DataSourceUtil.java:254)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.DataSourceUtil.testConnection(DataSourceUtil.java:251)
com.bea.console.utils.jdbc.JDBCUtils.testConnection(JDBCUtils.java:751)
com.bea.console.actions.jdbc.datasources.createjdbcdatasource.CreateJDBCDataSource.testConnectionConfiguration(CreateJDBCDataSource.java:479)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.FlowController.invokeActionMethod(FlowController.java:870)
org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.FlowController.getActionMethodForward(FlowController.java:809)
org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.FlowController.internalExecute(FlowController.java:478)
org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowController.internalExecute(PageFlowController.java:306)
org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.FlowController.execute(FlowController.java:336)
...***

I think it mainly says *The Network Adapter could not establish the connection*
However, I don't have much knowledge what to do to establish the connection properly. Thanks.

Comment: if your database is `local`, then use `localhost`

Comment: @SajanChandran Oracle for Mac OS?

Comment: is `localhost` not recognised in Mac OS ?

Comment: Are you trying to connect to a local database or a different server? What is your local IP and what does your JDBC url look like?

Comment: I didn't create any database. Do I need to create a database first ? I tried to put the *Host name*  as localhost, didn't work. With my previous Host name, the JDBC URL is : jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.131.173.138:1521:myTestDB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a real database with correct values in the jdbc URL:

i.e.

For example, if the database to which you want to connect resides on host prodHost, at port 1521, and system identifier (SID) ORCL, and you want to connect with user name scott and password tiger, then use either of the two following connection strings:

```
Using host:port:sid syntax:

String connString="jdbc:oracle:thin:@prodHost:1521:ORCL";
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand I need to create a database first to proceed.